# Group of covering transformations

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

The group of automorphisms of a covering $p: E \mapsto X$, to be denoted $Aut(E,p)$, is usually referred to as the group of covering transformations. If $p: E_1 \mapsto E_2$ is an isomorphism of coverings, then $Aut(E,p_2)=f \circ Aut(E,p_1) \circ f^{-1}$.
In order to proof this statement, let $H \in Aut(E,p_2)$ and $G \in Aut(E,p_1)$, then
$$
p_1=p_2 \circ f, \qquad \, p_1=p_1 \circ G \qquad \, p_2=p_2 \circ H
$$
So we have $p_1G=p_2Hf \implies p_2 fGf^{-1}=p_2 H$ but $p_2$ is surjective so the cancellation law doesn't hold.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Consider the two mappings $T \mapsto f \circ T \circ f^{-1}$ and $S \mapsto f^{-1}\circ S\circ f$.

Comment: This is abstract nonsense and has nothing to do with covering spaces etc. Just draw a diagram, you will see the equation.